# Can a noun functioning as modifier of a noun phrase fuse with the head?

Tags: ellipses, modifiers

In a section titled "**Fused modifier-heads**", *A Student's Introduction to English Grammar* says:

> The modifiers which most readily fuse with the head include these:
> •   **determinatives** used in modifier function following a determiner (e.g. *these **two***)
>
> •   **superlatives** and **comparatives** (*the **best***, *the **most important** of them*, *the **taller** of them*)
>
> •   **ordinal** numeral words (*the **second***, *the **eighth***)
>
> •   certain semantic categories of **adjective**, e.g. colour adjectives as in *the **blue*** and nationality adjectives that aren’t also count nouns, as in *the **French***, *the **English***, *the **Dutch*** (we don’t get **The Belgian are very courteous* because we use the count noun instead: *The Belgians are very courteous*).

Since a noun can also be modifier of an NP (noun phrase), I wonder if a noun functioning as modifier of an NP can fuse with the head.

In (a), for example, the nouns *labor* and *transportation* are modifiers of the respective NPs *labor secretary* and *transportation secretary*.

> a. The president nominated [XXX] for labor secretary and [YYY] for transportation secretary.

Can the modifier/noun *transportation* here fuse with the head *secretary* as in (b)?

> b. The president nominated [XXX] for labor secretary and [YYY] for transportation.

If (b) doesn't work, are there any examples where a noun functioning as modifier of an NP can fuse with the head?

Comment: When we say, Agriculture Ministry (In India), or Labour Department, similar fusing happens, doesn't it?

Comment: @RamPillai Please give a full-sentence example.

Comment: *b. The president nominated [XXX] for labor secretary and [YYY] for transportation*.

In (b) labor secretary is a title of an office. The noun1 + noun2 combination gives “noun2 associated with noun1 - the secretary associated with “labor”, and “labor” is understood as “matters concerning employment.” So, following the conjunction, when we see “transportation” we understand this as “*the same office in matters concerning* transportation”.

Answer (score 3):

No, the noun acting as a stunt adjective cannot fuse without causing semantic chaos.

Examples should make that fairly obvious:

> **The president nominated him for labor secretary and her for transportation.*
>
> **I ordered the duck soup and she ordered the chicken.* (incorrect assuming she ordered soup)
>
> **We gave Bob his tinfoil hat and Sally her witch.*

In *9.3 Fusion of internal modifier and head*, CGEL notes:

> The head does not fuse so readily with an internal modifier as with a
>   determiner, as evident from the ungrammaticality of such examples as:
>
> ```
> [20]   i *Because the existing bridge is too narrow, we will have to build [a new].
>       ii *The retreating troops were captured, but [the advancing] managed to escape. 
>      iii *Bill likes the linguistics lecturer, but I prefer [the sociology].
> ```
>
> The adjective *new*, the verb *advancing*, and the noun *sociology*
>   require a following head, such as ***one***.
>
> <sub>Source: *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, Ch. 5, §9.3</sub>

Things that can fuse, says *CGEL* in that same section, include "Modifiers denoting colour, provenance, and composition." Examples offered are:

```
[25]   i  Henrietta likes red shirts, and I like [blue].
      ii Knut wanted the purple wall paper,but I wanted [the mauve].
     iii Henrietta likes Russian vodka, and I like [Polish].
      iv Knut wanted the French caterers, but I wanted [the Italian].
       v I prefer cotton shirts to [nylon].
      vi Knut likes malt whisky, but I prefer [blended].
```

Now, those all look like adjectives . . . except in v; *cotton* and *nylon* are nouns. Or are they?

I will leave you here to explore attributive nouns vs. conversion / "zero-derivation" denominal adjectives (it's a vast subject with little consensus).

But before I go, I will proffer that I think *cotton* and *nylon*—like *stone* and *iron*—are actually fully converted to adjectives, and that is what allows fusion. Check this out:

> **4.1 Conversion from noun to adjective**
>
> There are some clues, though, to make sure conversion has taken place.
>   In the case of adjectives coming from nouns, the hints are quite easy:
>   they can be considered as cases of conversion only when they can
>   appear in predicative as well as in attributive form. If the denominal
>   adjective can be used attributively, we can affirm conversion has
>   happened. If it can only appear predicatively, it is merely a case of
>   partial conversion. 'Mahogany music box' (62) can be used in an
>   attributive way, "the music box is mahogany". This implies 'mahogany'
>   is a denominal adjective. However, in the predicative phrase 'antiques
>   dealers' (63) we cannot treat 'antiques' as an adjective because the
>   attributive form of this expression is ungrammatical (*dealers are
>   antique).
>
> <sub>Source: [Grammatical Conversion in English: Some new trends in
>   lexical
>   evolution](https://translationjournal.net/journal/31conversion.htm)</sub>

Adjective test:

> *The shirt is cotton.* (correct; *cotton* is a denominal adjective in *cotton shirt*)
>
> **The soup is duck.* (incorrect; *duck* is an attributive noun in *duck soup*)

Comment: I don't agree that "*The president nominated him for labor secretary and her for transportation" and "*I ordered the duck soup and she ordered the chicken [soup]" are absolutely unacceptable.

Comment: Also, note that [people do say things like "The soup was chicken"](https://books.google.com/books?id=V6szDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA41&lpg=PA41&dq=%22soup+was+chicken%22&source=bl&ots=m7U_UhrsNP&sig=ACfU3U0rlS0PivyfaX6ZBQgMgy12VypfNg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi_wpjYoJvoAhUEo54KHVH2B9UQ6AEwF3oECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22soup%20was%20chicken%22&f=false)

Comment: @herisson: For me, there's no way to recover *secretary* after *transportation*. And your example of *The soup was chicken* reads as *The soup was chicken [soup].* Not like *The soup was tasty.*

Comment: @herisson How acceptable is (b) to you? Barely acceptable or fully acceptable?

Comment: @TinfoilHat Since I don't have CGEL, I'd like to know if there is any other example of a noun/modifier fusing with the head than "I prefer cotton shirts to nylon".

Comment: How about: *I prefer paper bags to plastic.* One might think of *paper* here as an attributive noun—a noun that happens to be pressed into service as an adjective. But *paper* is now (since the 16th century) an adjective in its own right. See [paper](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/paper). So I guess what I am trying to say is: if it can fuse, it's not a noun, it was just born of one.